# Starting an asynchronous operation using RxJava without subscribing to an observable?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Let's say your DAO has this method that updates user records in the DB:

```
@Update
fun update(user: User): Single<Int>
```

Recently I started learning RxJava and so far I have seen lots examples like following:

```
// Example 1
disposable.add(dao.updateUser(user)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        Log.d(TAG, "response received")
    }
```

In the above example, I understand that as soon as the subscription starts, `updateUser()` will be executed on a worker thread and the subscriber will be notified and run in the main thread once the execution completes.

But what if you are not interested in the result of `updateUser()`, and all you want is just to execute `updateUser()` on a worker thread?

So far I have tried doing:

```
// Example 2
dao.updateUser(user)
```

or

```
// Example 3
dao.updateUser(user).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

But they didn't work. It seems the update requests are never executed, nothing was logged and records didn't change. I am guessing that's because there isn't any subscriber attached to it.

For now I am forcing it to work by attaching a random subscriber that doesn't really do anything like the one in `Example 1`. One of the problems with the approach is that I might need to make this request a lot and that might create a lot of dummy subscribers, not to mention that the code looks really bad.

Could you help me find a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But You already wrote answer for Your question.

You can just call:

```
dao.updateUser(user).subscribe()
```

If You want manipulate / jump between thread you are doing something like in Example 1.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could call `subscribe()` without a consumer.. Also from the source code, I noticed it does not `@CheckReturnValue`, while other overloaded methods with the same name do check if return value is used.